# Redirect old domain to new domain's homepage

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I want to redirect everything on old domain (but not the homepage because there is still content) to new domain's homepage.

Important: But I don't want to redirect the old homepage. Just the other subfolders like domain.com/*

How to do this? I think this code won't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ olddomain.com $ [ALEBO]
RewriteRule (. *) $ Http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R = 301, L]
</ IfModule>
```

Comment: Why you put spaces in `^ olddomain.com $`?Also try escaping `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

No spaces anywhere in your rule or condition. Also a dot in `RewriteRule` makes sure to match anything but landing page.

Comment: Thanks, the redirection works fine. But now the CSS and JS can't be load on homepage, I'm getting 503 error of loading the styles. What should be the problem?

Comment: When I delete the redirection it works fine. So problem is in the redirection REGEX I think :)

Comment: Also when there is no page on old domain like olddomain.com/test-site its redirects to newdomain.com/test-site and getting 404g error. 

Is it possible If there is no site on olddomain.com (getting 404 on olddomain) so redirect to newdomain.com homepage? Not the same page like on olddomain?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what is `redirection REGEX` here? Also you can add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` to make sure only existing files are redirected to new domain.